# Single quoted full path files in a text file can't do for loop processing mv: cannot stat ... No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, scripting

I have a test file which contains a space-separated files that I want to move/delete.

Example line:

```
'/data/owncloud/A0934095JG 1231/files/Photos/Paris 2016 08 28.jpg'
```

I want to move the files away to another directory in a for loop:

```
for i in $(cat marktodelete);do mv $i /data/willbedeleted/;done
```

But it gives me an error.

```
mv: cannot stat ‘'/data/owncloud/A0934095JG 1231/files/Photos/Paris 2016 08 28.jpg'’: No such file or directory
```

Why?

2nd problem after this how could I move actually this file to the new place with included the original directory somehow in the name, like the above file would like like this in the new place:

```
/data/willbedeleted/Paris 2016 08 28.jpg-/data/owncloud/A0934095JG 1231/files/Photos/
```

or because of the slash can be like this also, no problem

```
/data/willbedeleted/Paris 2016 08 28.jpg-data-owncloud-A0934095JG-1231-files-Photos
```

Comment: You cannot have space separated filenames when your filenames itself has spaces. Better to have one filename per line (assuming filename doesn't have line breaks).

Comment: so how can I delete or move these files ?

Comment: how that one would looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the 1st question, there are two problems related to the whitespaces
in the pathname. One is in the `for .. in ..` loop and the other is in the `mv` command. The word-spltting is caused unless you double-quote the filenames. On the other hand, if you enclose the filenames with quotes in the resource file `marktodelete`, the quoting character is interpreted as a part of the filename.

Assuming one line in the file contains one filename, please try instead:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    i=${i#\'}    # remove leading single quote
    i=${i%\'}    # remove trailing single quote
    mv -- "$i" /data/willbedeleted/
done < marktodelete
```

As of the 2nd question, you can change the destination filenames with:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    i=${i#\'}    # remove leading single quote
    i=${i%\'}    # remove trailing single quote
    basename="${i##*/}"     # extracts filename
    orgdir="${i%/*}"        # extracts directory name
    newname="${basename}-${orgdir//[\/ ]/-}"
    mv -- "$i" "/data/willbedeleted/$newname"
done < marktodelete
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, finally I had to add another sed because some files have space after the file name so I had to remove all. I'll use your while instead of a for, it works with for loop as well if you specify the IFS correctly but the wile is more elegant :D Thank you.